# How to specify a data object for a WinForms datagridview in code?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I created a class with public properties and added it as a new DataSource object in a WinForms project.

```
Public Class ICS211DetailCols
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property fk211 As Integer
    Public Property StateAbbreviation As String
    ...
End Class
```

When I add a DataGridView control to a Form from the ToolBox, the DataSource property can be set to the BindingSource created by the DataSource object (ex. ICS211DetailColumnsBindingSource) by selecting it from the **Other Data Source** ComboBox and all columns will appear in the DataGridView Columns collection.

I would now like to create a DataGridView in code and associate the same BindingSource but cannot seem to find any information on how this is accomplished. Is this even possible to do in code, or must I add the columns to the collection individually?

Comment: Does [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0wfd4yz(v=vs.90).aspx) help?

Comment: Thanks. It did help in convincing me that the column collection must be individually built.